# Using VLookup To Count A Total

Tags: excel, count, sum, vlookup

In Excel, for example, I have 4 columns like this.

```
Name QTY  Name QTY
A     1    A    2
B     5    C    5
C     10   B    3
D     6    D    10
E     12   E    11
F     14   G    15
G     10   H    5
I     5
```

Then I want another column for Total that will count the QTYs when the Names match, looking something like this.

```
Name  Total QTY  
A         3   
B         8   
C         15 
D         16    
E         23   
F         29  
G         15
H         5
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Please provide an example of the end result you want to see, its not clear from your question

Comment: I edited my post. Sorry about that.

Comment: How, in the total, is B = 10? I see 5 + 3? and how is C = 13, not 15?  Also, do you require `Vlookup()`, or are alternatives okay?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, my edit was wrong. I'll correct it now. And Vlookup() is not required. I'm really just looking for the easiest way to get the end result. I am looking at your comment now and it looks like it will help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine two SUMIF:

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,F2,$B$2:$B$8)+SUMIF($C$2:$C$8,F2,$D$2:$D$8)`.

Assuming your data looks like this:
[image]